# I don't understand the usage of "either" in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, slang

> "I couldn't sleep last night. I bet you guys couldn't either".

Does the second sentence mean "*I bet you too, guys*"?

Is it correct to use "*either*" like that or is it just slang?

Comment: "I bet you too" doesn't make sense! That would mean that I had bet some money or something, and now I was betting who ever I was talking to.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to say that you, or someone else, has done the same as someone else, you use **too**, indeed.

However, in the negative, if you want to say they have **not** done something, just like someone else has **not** done it, you use **either**.

> I enjoyed watching the game. I bet you guys enjoyed it **too**!

But:

> The game was boring, I could not watch it till the end! I bet you guys could not **either**!

Alternatively, you can substitute *neither* for *not either* (thanks WS2):

> The game was boring, I could not watch it till the end! I bet you guys could **neither**!

If you would use **too** in a negative sentence, it means something else:

> I scored 1000 points in this game. I bet you cannot do it too!

Notice that now, I *did* score those points, and I am betting that someone else can **not** do it.

Comment: Nice analysis. I'll just add that _too_ is probably best classed as an **additive focus particle** here: 'The [additive] focus particle indicates that its referent is added to a previously mentioned set of referents.' ... For example: _John plays guitar.... I do too._ [various websites] I suppose 'either' is also an additive focus particle, _its referent being added to a previously mentioned set of referents attaching to a negative verb construction_.

Comment: 'The game was boring, I could not watch it till the end! I bet you guys could not either!' I think I would say '...I bet you could neither.'

Comment: Good point. I'll add that :)

Comment: @WS2 Actually, I wouldn't say that, though I might say _'...I bet neither could you.'_ That's because _neither_ and _nor_ are used in this sense at the beginning of clauses and short answers instead of _not .. either_ - but you can't put them at the end of a clause.

Comment: Thanks,Edwin, for the terminology, which I was looking for. However, to add my bit, I would say 'I couldn't either', or 'neither could I', rather than the alterhatives above. I certainly wouldn't say 'could not either' or 'could neither'.